# Add Text to Diagrams

Tags: plotting, regions, labeling, text

```
RegionPlot[{x<1 && y<1 &&x+2(x y)^(1/2)<1, 
 y<1&&x>1&&1/x+2(y/x)^(1/2)<1, 
 ((1/(x y))^(1/2) +(x/( y))^(1/2))^(2)<4 , 
 x y<1/4&&y>1&&x+2(x y)^(1/2)<1, 
y/ x<1/4&&y>1&&1/x+2(y/x)^(1/2)<1}, {x, 0,9}, {y, 
  0, 3}, LabelStyle ->{15,Bold,Black},PlotPoints->100, 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> True,FrameLabel->{ "|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(1\)]\) / \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(3\)]\)|","|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(2\)]\)|"
},RotateLabel -> False, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 10],  
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Cyan, Yellow, Orange}]
```

I have the above code to plot a few regions. Now I want to label each regions as done in a similar image shown below. I want to add R_1 , R_2 .. exactly as shown in the picture. How can I do it in Mathematica itself? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
funcs = {x < 1 && y < 1 && x + 2 (x y)^(1/2) < 1, 
    y < 1 && x > 1 && 1/x + 2 (y/x)^(1/2) < 1, 
    ((1/(x y))^(1/2) + (x/( y))^(1/2))^(2) < 4 , 
    x y < 1/4 && y > 1 && x + 2 (x y)^(1/2) < 1, 
   y/ x < 1/4 && y > 1 && 1/x + 2 (y/x)^(1/2) < 1};

labels = TraditionalForm[Subscript[ℛ, #]]&/@ Range[Length[funcs]];

framelabels = TraditionalForm /@ {Abs[Row[{Subscript[u, 1], "/", Subscript[u, 3]}]], 
   Abs[Subscript[u, 2]]}
```

You can use the option [`PlotLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html):

```
RegionPlot[funcs, {x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLabels -> Join[Placed[#,Center] & /@ labels[[;;3]],
   {Placed[labels[[4]], {{.2, 1.15}, {.5, .5}}], Placed[labels[[5]], Center]}], 
 LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> framelabels, 
 RotateLabel -> False, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 10],  
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Cyan, Yellow, Orange}] /. Opacity[2/3]->Opacity[0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You just nailed it. Except for the R_4. It is not transparent so a part of the region is not visible

Answer (score 3):

You could try `Epilog`

```
RegionPlot[{x < 1 && y < 1 && x + 2 (x y)^(1/2) < 1, 
  y < 1 && x > 1 && 1/x + 2 (y/x)^(1/2) < 1,
  ((1/(x y))^(1/2) + (x/(y))^(1/2))^(2) < 4,
  x y < 1/4 && y > 1 && x + 2 (x y)^(1/2) < 1, 
  y/x < 1/4 && y > 1 && 1/x
     + 2 (y/x)^(1/2) < 1}, {x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black},
 PlotPoints -> 100, Axes -> True, Frame -> True,
 RotateLabel -> False, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 10],
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Cyan, Yellow, Orange},
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Epilog -> {
   {Style[Text["R3", {2.8, 2.2}], 14]},
   {Style[Text["R5", {8, 1.2}], 14]},
   {Style[Text["R1", {.2, .2}], 10]},
   {Style[Text["R4", {.2, 1.2}], 10]},
   {Style[Text["R2", {6, 0.5}], 14]}
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can play with `Style` and `Text` to change these.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to get the particular font of 'R' with subscript exactly as in picture I uploaded?